# C++ Quick Sort giving me Stack Overflow

Tags: c++, sorting, stack-overflow, quicksort

I was given pseudocode and I pretty much have the form of it correct, but I don't get why it gives me a Stack Overflow every single time I try to run quick sort in Visual Studio. Below is the function I've made.

```
template <typename T>
void quickSort(T list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{ 
int i = lowerBound;
int j = upperBound;
T tmp;
T pivot = list[(lowerBound + upperBound)] / 2;

while (i <= j)
{
    while (list[i] < pivot)
    {
        i = i + 1;
    }

    while (list[j] > pivot)
    {
        j = j - 1;
    }

    if (i <= j)
    {
        tmp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = tmp;
        i = i + 1;
        j = j - 1;
    }
}
if (lowerBound < j)
    quickSort(list, lowerBound, j);
if (i < upperBound)
    quickSort(list, i, upperBound);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I was mildly confused. I was thinking that your quick sort somehow always directed you to this website. This is a sign I need to sleep.

Comment: shouldn't pivot be list[(lowerBound + upperBound) /2] ?

Comment: @thebenman You were absolutely correct. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidM No problem. In case you want a code review check out this almost similar question on Code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77782/quick-sort-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `T pivot = list[(lowerBound + upperBound)] / 2;` to 
`T pivot = list[(lowerBound + upperBound)/2];`